# caching proxy server for windows 8

Tags: windows, http-proxy

I need to setup a local caching proxy server on windows 8 so I can cache some web contents to both speed up page loads and prevent our low quality internet connection from letting us down every now and then.

in our country even some js & css files on the Google search page are censored due to our government's sick policies! I can load these files using vpn connections but sometimes they even interrupt vpn connections (and other ways of going around the censorship).

I used to use squid proxy for windows a long time ago, but it seems that development of squid for windows has been stalled for a long time now.

Are there any better options than the old squid server for windows?

Comment: Run squid on Linux?

Comment: like I said, I'm looking for a caching proxy server for windows. installing Linux in not an option for me.

Comment: Run Squid on Linux in a VM on Windows.

Comment: Using a VM is a workaround. it's not good enough when there is a native windows application for it.

Comment: I went with SafeSquid. it seems to be working fine for now.

Comment: you could try WinGate, it's in active development still.

Answer (score 2):

Yesterday I tried CCProxy http://www.youngzsoft.net/ccproxy/
Try that too..

Try Polipo
http://www.pps.univ-paris-diderot.fr/~jch/software/polipo/

Download Windows binaries from https://archive.torproject.org/tor-package-archive/polipo/

I've used it and it's good.

Answer (score 0):

The officially sanctioned MS product for this purpose is MS Forefront Threat Management Gateway (formerly ISA Server). It will do this, plus quite a bit more, which makes it overkill. And it's pricey.

Having said that, someone did create a native port of Squid 2.7 to Windows. http://squid.acmeconsulting.it/Squid27.html

Comment: Squid 2.7 dates back to 2008 I guess. the latest version is 3.3.3. But I had never heard of MS forefront  TMG. I should give that a try too :)

Comment: Microsoft ISA/TMG is hitting End Of Life (if that matters). http://blogs.technet.com/b/server-cloud/archive/2012/09/12/important-changes-to-forefront-product-roadmaps.aspx I found a list of possibilities, but would require some study - http://www.web-caching.com/proxy-caches.html .. but then I'm only found this thread because I'm still looking for a proxy to replace TMG.

Answer (score -1):

I've tried Squid (Windows edition) and CCProxy. Both are fine options but the detour using these applications make them redundant unless you're managing a 100+ client network. Recently I even left OpenDNS because I realized that my ISP wasn't filtered/censored so there wasn't any need to jump another hoop. It basically boils down to what ISP services you have, the number of clients, and what you need. Do some ipconfig and tracert commands, and check out if access to websites still work.